# Is there an EventListener on mat-paginator last or first button?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, paginator

I need to listen when I especially **click** on mat-paginator last-button. Is there an event listener or a way to do this ?

I tried : `(page)="pageEvent = $event;emitPagination($event)"` but it does not return information about where I clicked.

and same for `(click) = event($event)`

HTML :

```
<mat-paginator #paginator 
    [length]="totalElements" 
    [pageSize]="5" 
    [showFirstLastButtons]="true" 
    (page)="pageEvent = $event;emitPagination($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

I expect to call a specific method when last button is **clicked**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MatPaginator have **method** `lastPage` you can trigger it from ts file like in this example:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.paginator.lastPage = () => this.yourMethodToTrigger();
 }

 yourMethodToTrigger(){
 console.log('Triggered!')
 }
```

Also can read from official documentation in section **methods** https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api

Comment: `MatPaginator#lastPage` is not intended to be overwritten and should instead be used to **only** navigate to the last page. You're probably looking for the `page` output, which emits a `PaginatorEvent` where you can check if the current index (`pageIndex`) is equal to the total number of items being paginated (`length`). (Other available properties can be found in the [docs for the `PageEvent` class](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api#PageEvent).) Alternatively, you could also call `MatPaginator#hasNextPage` to check if there's still another page.